# How to show power menu in flutter when a button is pressed

Tags: flutter

I want to open the power menu of a android phone when a button is pressed in flutter.
Is there any package or any other way to achive this ?

Something like this :

[image: Power menu]

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592715/how-to-show-power-menu-programmatically-in-android

Comment: But its for native and I want for flutter